# C# - Unique "Not All Code Paths Return A Value" issue

Tags: c#

I have a `public static IPAddress`

Here is my code:

```
try {
            IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Website);

            foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
            {
                return theaddress;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return IPAddress.Parse("Invalid Website!");
            /* dont worry about the line of code above this */
        }
```

The issue is all my *possible* code paths return a value.

What I am trying to do is resolve a website address to an Internet Protocol Address, if that does matter. I am not sure if a Try, Catch, Finally method would fix this, and if a Try, Catch, Finally method would fix it, how would I use it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No actually not all your return paths do. If `addresslist` is empty it will not return a value.

Comment: what if `addresslist` is empty?

Comment: You're not handling the default where the list is empty. Also, the foreach is pointless, as you're returning the first value anyway.

Comment: @scrappedcola the thing is, it is impossible to leave that empty with what I am doing, I am making a class library for the record.

Comment: But the compiler has no idea that it's impossible for the list to be empty.

Comment: @Kawjah You know that, and I know that, but the compiler can't prove that.

Comment: Put a return null after your catch, or some other default IPAddress.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi Error: Array creation must have array size or array initializer

Comment: On a side note, you can get the first address in the list of addresses using `addresslist.First()`. No need for the loop. Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` near the top of your code file.

Comment: @Kawjah: `Error: Array creation must have...` and array can have no elements, in which case your `foreach` does not iterate anything.

Comment: You could just return the first element of the array that is non-null. And just let the exception bubble up, or handle it and return null, or some other default IPAddress value.

Comment: What do you want to do if the list is empty? You could use `Enumerable.First()` which will throw if the input sequence is empty. Also using `IPAddress.Parse` is a strange way to throw an exception, just throw the exception you want explicitly.

Comment: `yield return` seems like a thing you might also want to look into for this function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. The probløem you have is that the compiled dont know if the `Dns.GetHostAddresses(Website)` returns `new IPAddress[0]` or not

```
try 
{
    IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Website);

    foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
    {
        return theaddress;
    }
}
catch
{
    return IPAddress.Parse(DefaultIP);
}

return null;
```

A better solution all together based of your code is.

```
try 
{
    IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Website);
    return addresslist.FirstOrDefault();
}
catch
{
    return IPAddress.Parse(DefaultIP);
}
```

or maybe if your foorloop does something magic, just throw  and catch on empty list.

```
try 
{
    IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Website);
    if(!addresslist.Any())
    {
        //Since you promise that it will never be empty then this is a exceptionable offence.
        throw new Exception("Host address list is empty");
        //But a simpler solution is just to return something.
    }
    foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
    {
        return theaddress;
    }
}
catch
{
    return IPAddress.Parse(DefaultIP);
}
```

Comment: What will happen when that string is attempted to be parsed as an IPAddress? That needs correction, I think.

Comment: Well, its not within the scope of the problem, but il adjust that.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you are only returning the first item with a return type of a single `IPAddress`

You can just do:

```
try
{ 
    return Dns.GetHostAddresses(Website).FirstOrDefault();
}
catch(Exception x)
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid website", x);
}
```

If the set happens to every be `Empty` it will just return null. Or if you want it to throw an exception for the case of not found.

```
try
{ 
    return Dns.GetHostAddresses(Website).First();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException iox)
{
    throw new Exception("IP list was empty", iox);
}
catch(Exception x)
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid website", x);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Simple and elegant. Nice job :)

Comment: @Eser true I'll adjust.